# Ruby parsing arguments of current URI

Tags: ruby, cgi, arguments

I'm using ruby to generate CGI (not on rails).

I want to parse arguments for a script running locally (with requests like `localhost:3000/apage.cgi?key=value`) in the same way I would do `ARGV[0]` for command line arguments.

When I try: `params = CGI.parse(request.query_string)`, I get `"undefined local variable or method request'".

EDIT: Here's the code. That's why I didn't put it in the first place :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'cgi'
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n"
#print CGI.parse(URI.parse(request.fullpath).query)
```

Comment: Could you give the full code? At a first glance, you're using `request` method or variable, which is not defined in your code.

Comment: precisely, which module is required to access this? (or simply get the current base url in pure ruby?) At this point, I'm just trying to output the parameters sent to my current script.

Comment: CGI interface assumes that you will read requests from standard input (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface ). Also, CGI server sets environment variables, which may be useful (like REQUEST_URI). In order to read data from STDIN, use method gets. In order to access env variables, use ENV['variable'].

Comment: many thanks, seems like print ENV['QUERY_STRING'] is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You script is right, you realy don't have `request` in this code. It's better to use fcgi instead of cgi, here is example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'fcgi'
require 'rack'


# this class made fcgi env compatible with rack
class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
  def initialize
  end

  def call(env)
    # here you can place initialization of you app
    request = Rack::Request.new env

    # here is params. You can also find all info about request in this object  
    request.params 

    # you app should return result in such format
    [200, "Content-type: text/plain", ['html']]
  end
end

Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run Rack::PathInfoRewriter.new
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have web server which supports CGI interface.

Try this script:

```
require 'cgi'

cgi = CGI.new
cgi.out{ ENV['REQUEST_URI'] }
```

This will response with text containing your request query.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to parse URLs I use either Ruby's built-in [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module, or the [Addressable](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/) gem.

Using URI, you'll need to append the protocol to get the right behavior:

```
URI.parse('http://' + 'localhost:3000/apage.cgi?key=value').query # => "key=value"
```

You can create a Hash of the values with a little bit more massaging:

```
Hash[URI.parse('http://localhost:3000/apage.cgi?key=value').query.split('&').map{ |q| q.split('=') }]
{
    "key" => "value"
}

Hash[URI.parse('http://localhost:3000/apage.cgi?key=value&foo=bar').query.split('&').map{ |q| q.split('=') }]
{
    "key" => "value",
    "foo" => "bar"
}
```

Similarly, using Addressable:

```
require "addressable/uri" # => true
uri = Addressable::URI.parse('http://' + 'localhost:3000/apage.cgi?key=value')
#<Addressable::URI:0x100c80978
    @uri_string = nil,
    @validation_deferred = false,
    attr_accessor :authority = nil,
    attr_accessor :host = "localhost",
    attr_accessor :path = "/apage.cgi",
    attr_accessor :port = 3000,
    attr_accessor :query = "key=value",
    attr_accessor :scheme = "http",
    attr_reader :hash = nil,
    attr_reader :normalized_host = nil,
    attr_reader :normalized_path = nil,
    attr_reader :normalized_port = nil,
    attr_reader :normalized_query = nil,
    attr_reader :normalized_scheme = nil
>
uri.query # => "key=value"
uri.query_values # => {"key" => "value"}
```